# How do I add a logarithmic regression in R

Tags: r, regression, logarithm

```r
x <- shapefile('42GP.shp')
A <- x$PatchArea1
df <- read.csv("CI.csv",header = T)
R <- df$mean
plot(R~A)
fit <- lm(R~log(A))
summary(fit)
coef(fit)
x=A
y=predict(fit,newdata=list(A)),interval="confidence"))
matlines(x,y,lwd=2)
```

My code is above, and the picture is as follow.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdZ4W.png
What can I fix my code, I need it draw like as follow. Thanks
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Afnt.png

Comment: Please provide a sample data

Comment: x <- 1:20
set.seed(1)
y <- 3*log(x)+5+rnorm(20)                                                                                                          I don't know how to modify the last three lines of codes.

Comment: Your code works for me, it produces something like the second picture. No idea where that first picture is coming from.

Comment: Thanks. but it is the same problem. Maybe some problem in this line? y=predict(fit,newdata=list(A)),interval="confidence"))

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tj1eum4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sample data, this work for me:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- 1:20 
set.seed(1)
y <- 3*log(x)+5+rnorm(20)

fit <- lm(y~log(x))

df <- data.frame(x = x, y =y , 
                 predict = fit$coefficients[1] +
                   fit$coefficients[2] * log(x))

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=predict))
```